# Linux supported 5.1 SPDIF out external sound cards

Tags: usb, sound, alsa, external-soundcard, spdif

My only requirement is to get 6 channel (5.1) digital audio out from USB and output it with a S/PDIF (optical/coaxial) port. So I'll connect the receiver (DAC) and it does the decoding + playback.

I'm looking for an external sound card with a working "S/PDIF out" with Linux for get the above job done.

I assume lot have experiences with using external sound cards with Linux, however there aren't much talking about having experiences with S/PDIF supported external sound card on Linux.
So please post your recommendations.

Comment: Don't buy **CM6206 chip** based devices. It isn't working for above particular purpose. Already tried with Fedora, Ubuntu, Elementary OS.

Comment: Did you find anything?